# Real life (NO echo server) SocketAsyncEventArgs tutorial needed

Tags: c#, tcp

Does anybody have know any sample/tutorial (a sample server using `SocketAsyncEventArgs` etc) code about the the enhanced asynchronous socket pattern introduced in .net 3.5? ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968780.aspx )

Pls. don't send me any samples with those well konown echo servers, they're not useful in this topic, they hide the some important things must be understood in this topic. Sample server should recieve data and send back something completely new/different to the client.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketasynceventargs.aspx) from codeproject should give you what you are looking for.

The tutorial seems pretty in depth and it consists of a server / client component. I think that part should satisy the constraint of not useing an echo server as you have access to the server as well as it's code for additional information.

Hope this helps

Comment: I also used this tutorial to make a TcpService, I had to add a few extras and removed some code, and it's on production for an year already without so many problems.